# Jquery Ajax - check date and time availability

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a booking form where I want to live check for availability. I managed to get this working just for checking if date is available, but having trouble also incorporating time into it.

This is how I do the check in Jquery / Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#time_select_2_hour").change(function(){
    $("#availability_1").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> checking...");


    var date1=$("#date1").val();
    var time_select_2_hour=$("#time_select_2_hour").val();

      $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"check.php",
            data:"date1="+date1,
            data:"time_select_2_hour="+time_select_2_hour,
                success:function(data){
                if(data==0){
                    $("#availability_1").html("<img src='tick.png' /> Tour  is available!");
                }
                else{
                    $("#availability_1").html("<img src='cross.png' /> Tour is fully booked, please choose another date or tour time.");
                }
            }
         });

    });

 });
```

And this is the check.php

```
  $date1=$_POST["date1"];
  $time=$_POST["time_select_2_hour"];

  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * from bookings where date1='$date1' AND time ='$time'");

  $find=mysql_num_rows($query);

  echo $find;
```

It's not throwing any errors, it just always says "Available" even if that combinations is already booked.

Comment: some prblms in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple `data` properties in the object literal defining your AJAX options and expect them both to work. Either use a single string:

```
data: "date1="+date1 + "&time_select_2_hour="+time_select_2_hour
```

Or use another object literal for the data:

```
data: {
    data1: date1,
    time_select_2_hour: time_select_2_hour
}
```

Note that even though the above may look like it would use the values of those variables as the properties on that object, it doesn't. Object property names/keys are always treated as strings, so it will be the literal value "data1".